# getting FATAL Exception while getting email address from device contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying get Email addresses from device contacts by using following code but i am getting **FATAL EXCEPTION**.
please help to resolve my issue.

```
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2292i7f5b6c750a4e6301/4631 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {kc.RajusLabs.iamhere/kc.RajusLabs.iamhere.Email}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 5
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 5
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at kc.RajusLabs.iamhere.Email.onActivityResult(Email.java:115)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
07-01 23:15:34.984: E/AndroidRuntime(22688):    ... 11 more
```

CODE::

```
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Uri contactData = data.getData();
          Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
          c.moveToFirst();
          String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String name1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
          String ContactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

       if(Integer.parseInt(name1) == 1){
         Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID+ " = " + ContactID, null, null);
         String emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NAME:: "+name+"ContactID:: "+ContactID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         textMessage.setText(name+ContactID);

          }
          }
            break;
```

and i am getting Exception at

> emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

Comment: You aren't calling moveToFirst on the emails cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling `moveToFirst()` on the `emails` cursor

Add

```
emails.moveToFirst();
```

after

```
 Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID+ " = " + ContactID, null, null);
```

And you should always verify that you successfully moved to the first position as AAnkit has suggested in his answer. I've updated your code to include these checks along with fixing your original problem and verifying that your DATA column isn't null

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    if (!c.moveToFirst())
        return;
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String name1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
    String ContactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    if (Integer.parseInt(name1) == 1) {
        Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + ContactID, null, null);
        if (!emails.moveToFirst())
            return;
        int index = emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)
        if (!emails.isNull(index)) {
            String emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(index);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NAME:: " + name + "ContactID:: " + ContactID,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textMessage.setText(name + ContactID);
        }

    }
}
break;
```

Comment: working fine thankyou.But getting Fatal Exception if that contact doesn't contain email id. :( How to skip those contacts shown in this view

Comment: Updated my answer to check for a null DATA column

Comment: @AAnkit Before you say I copied, please note my comment that answers the question before you even answered. I commented on your answer saying that you didn't actually fix the issue (instead of just putting a comment on the code that says "go fix it everywhere"). I gave you enough time to add detail to your answer before I answered. I'll upvote you so you don't feel bad about imaginary points.

Comment: Yes We are here to point out mistakes/issues OP facing, We can not go and write whole code for them, I mentioned my point about the bug in his code and it was perfect, No!! Cheers, Never mind. Will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

change below line

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

with

```
if(!c.moveToFirst())
 return;
```

Here C is cursor, Do same with other cursors as well like "emails"

you are trying to fetch values from empty cursor.

Comment: while it's true he should catch this, his exception is coming from the trying to call into the 'emails' cursor and not 'c'. The stacktrace clearly says the cursor isn't empty

Comment: @AAnkit still getting same exp at same line :(

Comment: @dymmeh Thanks for your concern But i mentioned this in the comment part.

KCRaju can you please follow the comment part of my post.